# How to set color for cell phpexcel into foreach loop

Tags: php, phpexcel

Now I want set text color for cell in phpexcel into foreach loop.
The foreach loop is something like :

```
$redBold = array(
            "font" => array(
                "bold" => true,
                "color" => array("rgb" => "FF0000"),
            ),
        );
$row = 5;
$count = 0
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($count++, $row, $value['type']?$value['type']:0);
    if ($value['type'] == 1) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($count . $row)->applyFromArray($redBold);
    }
}
```

this code is not understand `getStyle($count . $row )` because `$count . $row` should be `A6`... Is there way to set text in this case? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you get when you concatenate `$count . $row`?

`getStyle()` expects either a cell reference (e.g. `A1`, `C3`, `IV256`) or a cell range (e.g. `A1:C3`, `B2:D4`, `A2:IV256` etc.

You're simply concatenating two numbers, e.g. `0` and `5` to give `05` which is meaningless in terms of cell references/ranges

You need to convert `$count` (which you're using as a column index, to an actual column address before concatenating

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($count) . $row)->applyFromArray($redBold);
```

Note also that you're incrementing the column using the post-increment operator **before** trying to set the style for the cell, so it probably isn't going to give you the cell reference that you want

Comment: I know `$count . $row` isn't exactly but I don't know how to result this problem. How can I set exactly value for `getStyle()` ? I want to set `0` is `A`, `1` is `B` into column phpexcel.

Comment: You can get the column address using `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()` as shown in my answer