# PHPExcel Change Background color for each cell in foreach loop

Tags: php, phpexcel

Each event has its own background color stored in the database.

> Question How can I change the background of each cell for that row making sure that has correct background color.

I had a look here [How to set color for cell phpexcel into foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674195/how-to-set-color-for-cell-phpexcel-into-foreach-loop) but not understand it.

It prints out

```
A0 
B0 
C0 
D0 
A1 222222
B1 222222
C1 222222
D1 222222
A2 
B2 
C2 
D2
```

Function

```
$excelrow = 2;

    foreach ($excelresults as $excelresult => $excelvalue) {


        foreach (range('A', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $col) {

            echo $col . $excelresult .' '. $excelvalue['fill_color'] . '<br>';

            $cell = $col . $excelresult;

            $objPHPExcel
            ->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle($cell)
            ->getFill()
            ->getStartColor()
            ->getRGB($excelvalue['fill_color']);
        } 

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_title']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_date']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_start_time']);

        $excelrow++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the background colour (fill) for the cell, so you also have to set a fill style

```
if (!empty($color)) {
    // Set the fill style
    objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)
        ->getFill()
        ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
    // Set the colour for the fill
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)
        ->getFill()
        ->getStartColor()->setRGB($color);
}
```

There is a demonstration of this in the [/Examples folder](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/05featuredemo.inc.php#L201) and it is described in the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#formatting-cells)

Comment: That works but can you also change / set font color also

Comment: Yes you can.... there is a lot of [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User-Documentation-Overview-and-Quickstart-Guide) and [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples) available for setting all elements of style, and almost everything that you can do with the library